# List system properties in admin console

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, system-properties

Is it possible to retrieve a list of system properties in the WebLogic admin console?

More specifically, I would like to know what `System.getProperty("weblogic.Domain")` returns.

If it is not possible, is it possible to do with some command line tool shipped with WebLogic?

Googling *"list system properties weblogic"* mostly gives results on how to set system properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible from the admin console.
You can do this with the java tool "jcmd" :

```
jcmd <PID> VM.system_properties
```

Comment: Run jcmd without parameters to get a list of applicable PIDs. 

Alternatively, use jinfo - you get the same data, but jinfo can also connect to a remote process over the debug port.

Comment: Great, jcmd seems to do the job. Any proof that this cannot be done through the admin console?

Comment: In fact, you can do it with the admin console by view server log. These system properties are dumped in each server's log.